# Calabash Cucumber String internationalization (R.string.*) and using IDs

Tags: android, testing, internationalization, cucumber, calabash

I would like to use *calabash/cucumber* to test my android app and I am wondering why I can't find information about how to use internationalized strings in the scenarios.

Android uses `R.string.*` with the one or more xml files, and IDs for identifying a correct view.

Is it possible to use something like this in Calabash?

```
Given I see R.string.hello_world

Given i enter R.string.hello_world into inout field with id R.id.input_1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the functionality you are looking for is not implemented. However, calabash supports internationalization through the following macros:

```
Then /^I press text of translated l10key (\d+)$/ 

Then /^I press button of translated l10key (\d+)$/

Then /^I press menu item of translated l10key (\d+)$/

Then /^I press toggle button of translated l10key (\d+)$/ 

Then /^I wait for the translated "([^\"]*)" l10nkey to appear$/
```

More details [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md#internationalization)